# JavaScript SDK for Facebook Share Button with Redirect

Tags: javascript, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-share

I am simply trying to create a Facebook Share Button with a redirect to another URL only after the share has been submitted.

I have gone through the instructions to setup JavaScript SDK app which is setup and completed correctly.

I have then gone to https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/share-button/# and have selected to use the simple iframe code like below.

```
<iframe src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/share_button.php?href=http%3A%2F%2Ftcpros.co%2F2BLNv&layout=button&size=large&appId=899555603822655&width=73&height=28" width="73" height="28" style="border:none;overflow:hidden" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowTransparency="true" allow="encrypted-media"></iframe>
```

When the code has been pasted into my HTML page, the share button is visible and works correctly when I test it, but I need to know exactly how and where to add the redirect code that Facebook give you from here below... https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/feed-dialog

And this is the code...

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?
  app_id=145634995501895
  &display=popup
  &link=https%3A%2F%2Fdevelopers.facebook.com%2Fdocs%2F
  &redirect_uri=https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer
```

But obviously I do not know how or where exactly to add this code to the existing share button code so that it all works correctly and redirects the user to another URL immediately after they have shared on Facebook.

Can someone please help me out and show me an example the exact code that works as I have specified above?

If the code is suppose to be all together as one piece of code please show me an exact example, and if it's suppose to be sperate please show me exactly how?

I need a simple iframe code for the share button that immediately redirects after the share.

Thanks in advance.

I have already tested the share button and that part works fine, the issue is I need the correct code to redirect to another URL.

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?
  app_id=145634995501895
  &display=popup
  &link=https%3A%2F%2Fdevelopers.facebook.com%2Fdocs%2F
  &redirect_uri=https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer
```

Comment: "The URL to redirect to after a person clicks a button on the dialog. Required when using URL redirection." - so that should redirect on EVERY button click, even on cancel. what is the use case, why do you only want to redirect after share? why would you NOT redirect a user if he does not share?

Comment: Hi, I would like someone to show me an example of the actual full code for this so that I can use it correctly? If the user does not share then they should not be redirected. They should only be redirected if they actually share. I wish to use redirect after share because the user will be sharing to receive my free content on my website.

Comment: alright, that´s why i was asking. what you are trying to do is not allowed, don´t try to do that. you can´t reward users in any way for sharing, or gate content behind a share. that´s why facebook made it impossible to check if someone really shared something.

Comment: Thanks for your excellent explanation Luschn, you may have just saved my Facebook account from certain doom! So my question then is there any way at all possible to do this another way? If so please list the options so that I can research further. Thanks in advance.

Comment: what other way, if it´s not allowed anyway?